# QLIKVIEW - Setting limit while building Hierarchy

Tags: hierarchy, qlikview

I'm new to `QlikView` and trying to build charts using Hierarchy concept of `Qlikview`.

Background of what I'm doing - Pulling data from MySQL database and generating charts in `Qlikview`. I have a resultant table containing ID, Name and ParentID, SomeCount that I get by firing a SQL query.

Additionally using this below query -

```
Hierarchy(ID,Parent,Name,ParentName,Name,Path,'/','Depth')
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that I get the entire child tree while clicking on a parent. However, I just the immediate children while clicking on a Parent. For Example -

```
--- Parent
    ------Child 1
    -----------SubChild1
    -----------SubChild1
    -----------Sub-child1
    -------Child 2
    -------Child 3
```

For the above example - while clicking on Parent, I need only Child 1, Child 2 and Child 3 to be shown. However, currently, even SubChild1, SubChild2, SubChild3 comes along with it.

[This is what is happening right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Mrt.png)

[This is what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NacL.png)

Is it possible to set a limit while generating charts? Kindly help.

Comment: I don't understand your question...are you alking about list box or table (chart). anyways, if you want to limit the number of levels, just load the table again using "where Depth<=X" (x is an integer)

Comment: Question is edited with relevant screenshots for better understanding. I need the limit to be set in my Bar Chart as well in my list box tree view. I am getting my data in Qlikview using a stored procedure in my MySQL database. @EldadT

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing that. the quickest is to use in the bar chart dimension the `name2` dimension that the Hierarchy function creates.

Hierarchy creates `name` dimensions for each depth, so if you have 3 levels of depth you should have `name1`, `name2` & `name3`.